# How to load counter form current text in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem to  load counter from where it left count.
My code is like this

In

```
viewDidLoad()
{
    if (!_currentTimeInSeconds) {

           }_currentTimeInSeconds = 0 ;
     if (!_myTimer) {
            _myTimer = [self createTimer];
        }
}
- (NSTimer *)createTimer {
    return [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                            target:self
                                          selector:@selector(timerTicked:)
                                          userInfo:nil
                                           repeats:YES];
}



- (NSString *)formattedTime:(int)totalSeconds
{
    int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
    int minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
    int hours = totalSeconds / 3600;

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d",hours, minutes, seconds];
}
- (void)timerTicked:(NSTimer *)timer {

    _currentTimeInSeconds++;

    clockLabel.text = [self formattedTime:_currentTimeInSeconds];

}
-(void)updateTime
{
    NSDate *date= [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]; //for hour and minute

    formatter1.dateFormat = @"hh:mm:ss";// use any format

    clockLabel.text = [formatter1 stringFromDate:date];
}
```

**For Save**

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 Timmer=clockLabel.text;
 [defaults setValue:Timmer forKey:@"Timmer"];
 [defaults synchronize];
```

**For Retrive**

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
Timmer=[defaults objectForKey:@"Timmer"];
clockLabel.text=Timmer;
```

This code is setting value from 0. 
I need to set the value from where I left count.How to do this?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `NSUserDefaults`!?

Comment: User Nsuserdefault or store value globally and retrive it '

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya Yes I have try that but counter restart from 0.

Comment: @luk2302 Yes I have try that but counter restart from 0

Comment: Your shown code does not demonstrate your effort of using `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: @Muju when you store a value in NSUserdefault ?

Comment: Whenever you are opening app its assiging _currentTimeInSeconds = 0, then how it will work? where are getting it? check code again, where assigning from defaults

Comment: @Muju you need to store second,minute,hour in nsuserdefault

Comment: @Muju check this video https://www.dropbox.com/s/rlwyn80hpt6irri/timerdemo.mov?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the count even after you quit and relaunch the app, then you should save/store the value into `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: Yes I try NSUserDefaults but counter restart from o.

Comment: Then the saving and retrieving mechanism you are using is wrong. It would be helpful if you can post your code here.

Comment: You need to use `set​Object:​for​Key:​` and not `setValue:forKey`.
https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1414067-setobject?language=objc

Comment: Ok. But it restarting count from 0.

Answer (score 0):

**Just Set value in NSUserDefaults when you leave your controller . And this whole code tested and its work completely fine. see above commented video.**

```
var _currentTimeInSeconds : Int = Int()
var _myTimer : Timer = Timer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        _currentTimeInSeconds = 0 ;
        _myTimer = self.createTimer()
 }

func createTimer()-> Timer {
        return Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(timerTicked), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
func timerTicked(_ timer: Timer) {
    _currentTimeInSeconds += 1;
    label.text = self.formattedTime(self._currentTimeInSeconds)

}
func formattedTime(_ totalSeconds: Int) -> String {
    let seconds: Int = totalSeconds % 60
    let minutes: Int = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60
    let hours: Int = totalSeconds / 3600
    return String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
}
func updateTime() {
        let date = Date()
        let formatter1 = DateFormatter()
        //for hour and minute
        formatter1.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
        // use any format
        label.text = formatter1.string(from: date)
}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(true)
        print(_currentTimeInSeconds)
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.setValue(_currentTimeInSeconds, forKey: "Timmer")
        defaults.synchronize()
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if  (defaults.object(forKey: "Timmer") != nil){
            _currentTimeInSeconds = defaults.object(forKey: "Timmer") as! Int
            print(_currentTimeInSeconds)
        }
 }
```

**Happy Coding.**

Comment: But I need to start counter from counter value.Like if counter is 0.0.07 then it will 0.0.8 and so on.

Comment: @Muju i comment something in viewwillappear() read it and impliment this code i already use this in my code so

Comment: No it restarting count from 0.

Comment: @Muju _currentTimeInSeconds set this value in userdefault and retrive it and just set it value in viewwillappear() and dont forget to start timer method

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    timeSec=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"timeSec"]] intValue];
    timeMin=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"timeMin"]] intValue];
    [self StartTimer];
}
-(void) StartTimer
{
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerTick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    self.lbl_timer.text=@"00:00";

}
- (void)timerTick:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    timeSec++;
    if (timeSec == 60)
    {

        timeSec = 0;
        timeMin++;
    }
    self.lbl_timer.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", timeMin, timeSec];;
}
```

when you back to the screen that time add this code.like back button or close button action

```
[timer invalidate];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:timeSec forKey:@"timeSec"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:timeMin forKey:@"timeMin"];
```

Comment: Your code is used to create timer.I need to start timer from where I left it.

Comment: @Muju this code is right because when you open first time app than start to 0 than after when you back to the screen than start with your last timer value